# Drag and drop in tableView cell

Tags: uitableview, swift4.2

I have implemented drag and drop functionality in tableView. The problem is when I drag and drop the cell, index at dropped place remain same as of picked position index. How can I keep the drop position index unchanged.

For Example: I have two cell cell-0 and cell-1 both having `UILable`. After dragging cell-1 to 0th index, my table shows: 
cell-1 
cell-0

and if I amend any changes in cell-0 label, it makes changes in label of cell-1.

any solution to keep the cell index as it is after drag and drop. Or any other solution will be appreciated.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let movedObject = self.tableStoryArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
    tableStoryArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    tableStoryArray.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    debugPrint("\(sourceIndexPath.row) => \(destinationIndexPath.row)")

}
```

Comment: So, your data is not getting change as per the index in UITableView data source array?

Comment: Yes,if I dragged 1st cell to third position and make any changes in 3rd then it gets reflect on 1st cell.